# How to pass options over to izimodal (JS) from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, izimodal

Want to get [iziModal](http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com) to work. As a beginner the documentation is a bit daunting.

It works fine, but I cannot pass the available options over to the script. The documentation for that is [here](http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com) under 'Data Attributes'.

This is my **HTML** code:

```
<div id="modal" data-iziModal-title="My Title">
    <button data-izimodal-iframeurl="http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com" data-izimodal-open="#modal-iframe">iFrame</button>
</div>
```

And here the **JS**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#modal-iframe').iziModal('open', event); // Use "event" to get URL href
});

$("#modal-iframe").iziModal({
    iframe: true,
    iframeURL: "http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com"
});
```

All I want is for the popup to display the title attribute and by extension all other attributes, of course. The documentation says that "all options can be set via data-attrs."

You might notice that the *iframeurl* is set twice (in HTML and again in JS). Take it out in JS and it will stop working... just as another example of that issue.

Does anyone know this script and what I might have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

The documentation is somewhat unclear. So here is the solution for anyone trying to figure this out too. The *id* in the *div* has to match with data of the following elements. To explain:

```
<div id="modal-iframe" data-izimodal-iframeurl="http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com" data-iziModal-title="My Title"></div>
    <button data-izimodal-open="#modal-iframe">iFrame</button>
```

In the example the *div id* is set to "modal-iframe". To get the button to respond with all the options, the button references the ID with data-izimodal-open="#modal-iframe". If the names don't match, it won't work.

Important: all options must be set in the *div*. In the example you see *data-iziModal-title="My Title" set correctly. Thus if placed into the  it will not work.

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

**EDIT**

To clarify further: the JS code is fine. No changes necessary for it to work. You may change it's options, of course. The options in the HTML will always have preference over the ones set in the JS.